# Kotlin overriding supertype variables

Tags: kotlin

Consider two classes:

```
abstract class ParentRepository {}

class ChildRepository : ParentRepository {}

abstract class ParentClass {
    protected abstract var repository: ParentRepository
}

class ChildClass : ParentClass {
    override var repository: ChildRepository
}
```

The last part won't work:

```
override var repository: ChildRepository
```

It will complain:

```
Type of 'repository' doesn't match the type of the overridden var-property 'protected abstract var repository: ParentRepository
```

I understand the problem, but I don't see the reason why this shouldn't work – ChildRepository is an instance of ParentRepository and this is a common thing I am used to from Java.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to declare `repository` as val. You can still override it as var:

```
protected abstract val repository: ParentRepository

override var repository: ChildRepository
```

Answer (score 8):

You have to consider that in *Kotlin* properties are a set of getters and setters. While a `val` only has a getter, a `var` also defines a setter. Thus you'd be able to set `repository` to a `ParentRepository` instance which might not be an instance of `ChildRepository`.

If you consider the variances for generics, you'll see the same behaviors. While you can use **covariance** `<out T>` for getters, you have to use **contravariance** `<in T>` for setters.

Answer (score 0):

Use keyword `open`:

```
protected open var repository: ParentRepository
```

Comment: We don't need `override` keyword?